# Python class to keep escape sequences

Tags: python, class

I have created simple class to keep escape seqs:

```
class Color:
    HEAD = '\033[95m'
    OKBL = '\033[94m'
    OKGR = '\033[92m'
    FAIL = '\033[93m'
    WARN = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDR = '\033[4m'
```

to use them in console outputs like so:

```
print(Color.WARN + "Output file will be overwritten!" + Color.ENDC)
```

now get message from linter that class has no `__init__` method.

Is it OK and I can simply ignore this warning or what would be pythonic way here?

Comment: I can not reproduce this error. Are you sure it is nowhre else in the code?

Comment: Tested in both Python-3.5.3 and Python-2.7.13

Comment: I also not getting any ERROR, could you please specify steps to reproduce it

Comment: It's not an error, it's a style warning. You could make it an [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead.

Comment: If you're only using the class for class attributes, then you can ignore the warning. It might be more pythonic to use a dictionary or [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-a-descriptive-string), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__()` method is used while creating an object from class. If you do not want to create any objects you do not have to define it. However, if you only want to it use to separate namespaces you could also simply move it to separate module.

Comment: Did I get it right that moving it to separate module serves only one purpose - to eliminate linter's warning?

Comment: Not only. It's another way of organizing your code in a clean way.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the pythonic way to assign variables inside the class and access them outside.

```
class Color:
  def __init__(self):
    self.HEAD = '\033[95m'
    self.OKBL = '\033[94m'
    self.OKGR = '\033[92m'
    self.FAIL = '\033[93m'
    self.WARN = '\033[91m'
    self.ENDC = '\033[0m'
    self.BOLD = '\033[1m'
    self.UNDR = '\033[4m'

color = Color()
print(color.WARN + "Output file will be overwritten!" + color.ENDC)
```